# Excel concatenation quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate several fields and want certain fields to start and end with quotes ("....."). When I put a cell (B2) inside this, the cell (B2) is shown as plain text with quotes around it.

```
CONCATENATE("""B2""") -> "B2"

CONCATENATE("""B2""") -> "(whatever is in cell B2)"
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this:

```
CONCATENATE(""""; B2 ;"""")
```

@widor provided a nice solution alternative too - integrated with mine:

```
CONCATENATE(char(34); B2 ;char(34))
```

Comment: This is working for me ->   CONCATENATE("""", B2 ,"""")

Answer (score 17):

Use `CHAR`:

```
=Char(34)&"This is in quotes"&Char(34)
```

Should evaluate to:

```
"This is in quotes"
```

Comment: would be interesting to know, which of those solutions is faster on a big scale - otherwise I find them quite equal. Anyone tested this?

Answer (score 12):

You can also use this syntax: (in column D to concatenate A, B, and C)

```
=A2 & " """ & B2 & """ " & C2
```

[image: Excel formula to concatenate with quotes]

Answer (score 1):

easier answer - put the stuff in quotes in different cells and then concatenate them!

```
B1: rcrCheck.asp
C1: =D1&B1&E1
D1: "code in quotes" and "more code in quotes"  
E1: "
```

it comes out perfect (can't show you because I get a stupid dialog box about code)

easy peasy!!

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but it was solved over a year ago ;) your solution wasn't an option

Answer (score 0):

I was Forming some Programming Logic Used **CHAR(34)** for Quotes at Excel :
A small Part of same I am posting which can be helpfull ,Hopefully

```
1   Customers
2   Invoices
```

Formula Used :

> =CONCATENATE("listEvents.Add(",D4,",",CHAR(34),E4,CHAR(34),");")

Result :

```
listEvents.Add(1,"Customers");
listEvents.Add(2,"Invoices");
```